# can't edit line in python's command line in Linux

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I'm running the Python CLI under Linux:

```
bla:visualization> python
Python 2.1.1 (#18, Nov  1 2001, 11:15:13) 
[GCC egcs-2.91.66 19990314/Linux (egcs-1.1.2 release)] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

For some reason the arrow keys and the delete key don't work:

**delete:**

```
>>> x^H^H^H
```

**up arrow:**

```
>>> x^[[A^[[A
```

etc...

How can I make these work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is that your Python installation was likely not compiled with the `readline` library. You can confirm this by trying to import the `readline` module:

```
import readline
```

You should get an error when you import if `readline` is not present.

If this is the case, there's not much you can do other than recompile Python with the `readline` library, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Install iPython ( http://ipython.scipy.org/ but can be installed using easy_install or pip), it is much much better than the default CLI.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your terminal from the shell, with [`stty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty). Pay special attention to the special characters `erase` and `kill`. Your Python installation is 8 years old, consider updating to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install readline-devel to get this to work:

yum install readline-devel

Now my python command line editing keystrokes work properly.